# Qcombobox with Qlabel and signal&slot

Tags: python, pyqt5, qcombobox, qlabel

I have a Qgroupbox which contains Qcombobox with Qlabels, I want to select a value from Qcombobox and display the value as Qlabel. I have the complete code, even I do print value before and after within function every thing works as it should, Only display `setText` wont set text to Qlabel and update it.

Current screen

[image]

What I want

[image]

I've corrected signal code, when `Qgroupbox` in it `Qcombobox` appears or value would be changed, `self.activation.connect(......)` would emit an `int` of the index. to ensure that would work I print `it-value` inside the `def setdatastrength(self, index)`, see figure below indeed it works, then argument would be passed to function `self.concreteproperty.display_condata(it)` would be called and do a print of value inside  `def display_condata(self, value)` to make sure about value passing, as shown figure below, it does work. This line code `self.con_strength_value.setText(fmt.format(L_Display))`
wont assign value to Qlabel.

[image]

The script

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class secondtabmaterial(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(secondtabmaterial, self).__init__(parent)

        self.concretewidgetinfo = ConcreteStrengthInFo()

        Concrete_Group = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(self)
        Concrete_Group.setTitle("&Concrete")
        Concrete_Group.setLayout(self.concretewidgetinfo.grid)


class ConcreteStrengthComboBox(QtWidgets.QComboBox):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(ConcreteStrengthComboBox, self).__init__(parent)


        self.addItems(["C12/15","C16/20","C20/25","C25/30","C30/37","C35/45"
                     ,"C40/50","C45/55","C50/60","C55/67","C60/75","C70/85",
                                                        "C80/95","C90/105"])

        self.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Helvetica", 10, QtGui.QFont.Normal, italic=False))

        self.compressive_strength = ["12","16","20","25","30","35","40",
                                      "45","50","55","60","70","80","90"]


class ConcreteProperty(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ConcreteProperty, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Helvetica", 10, QtGui.QFont.Normal, italic=False))


        concretestrength_lay = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        fctd = "\nfcd\n\nfctd\n\nEc"
        con_strength = QtWidgets.QLabel(fctd)
        self.con_strength_value = QtWidgets.QLabel(" ")
        concretestrength_lay.addWidget(con_strength)
        concretestrength_lay.addWidget(self.con_strength_value, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignRight)
        self.setLayout(concretestrength_lay)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int)
    def display_condata(self, value):
        try:
            L_Display = str(value)
            print("-------- After ------")
            print(L_Display, type(L_Display))

            fmt = "{}mm"
            self.con_strength_value.setText(fmt.format(L_Display))

       except ValueError:
           print("Error")

class ConcreteStrengthInFo(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ConcreteStrengthInFo, self).__init__(parent)

        self.concreteproperty = ConcreteProperty()
        self.concretestrengthbox = ConcreteStrengthComboBox()

        self.concretestrengthbox.activated.connect(self.setdatastrength)

        hbox = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        concrete_strength = QtWidgets.QLabel("Concrete strength: ")
        hbox.addWidget(concrete_strength)
        hbox.addWidget(self.concretestrengthbox)

        self.grid = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.grid.addLayout(hbox, 0, 0)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.concreteproperty, 1, 0)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int)
    def setdatastrength(self, index):
        it = self.concretestrengthbox.compressive_strength[index]
        self.concreteproperty.display_condata(it)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = secondtabmaterial()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Above code is corrected and final. Now it works as it should.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is that your receiving slot doesn't match any of the available `.activated` signals.

```
self.activated.connect(self.setdatastrength)

@QtCore.pyqtSlot()
def setdatastrength(self):
    index = self.currentIndex()
    it = self.compressive_strength[index]
    print(it)
    self.concreteproperty.display_condata(it)
```

The `QComboBox.activated` signal emits either an `int` of the index, or a `str` of the selected value. [See documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html#activated).

You've attached it to `setdatastrength` which accepts doesn't accept any parameters (aside from `self`, from the object) — this means it doesn't match the signature of either available signal, and won't be called. If you update the definition to add the index value, and accept a single `int` it should work.

```
self.activated.connect(self.setdatastrength)

@QtCore.pyqtSlot(int)  # add the target type for this slot.
def setdatastrength(self, index):
    it = self.compressive_strength[index]
    print(it)
    self.concreteproperty.display_condata(it)
```

After the update — the above looks now to be fixed, although you don't need the additional `index = self.currentIndex()` in `setdatastrength` it's not doing any harm.

Looking at your code, I think the label *is* being updated. The issue actually is that you can't see the label at all. Looking at the init for `ConcreteProperty`

```
class ConcreteProperty(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ConcreteProperty, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Helvetica", 10, QtGui.QFont.Normal, italic=False))


        self.concretestrength_lay = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        fctd = "\nfcd\n\nfctd\n\nEc"
        con_strength = QtWidgets.QLabel(fctd)
        self.con_strength_value = QtWidgets.QLabel(" ")
        self.concretestrength_lay.addWidget(con_strength)
        self.concretestrength_lay.addWidget(self.con_strength_value, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft)
```

The reason the changes are not appearing is that you create *two* `ConcreteProperty` objects, one in `ConcreteStrengthInfo` and one in `ConcreteStrengthComboBox`. Updates to the combo box trigger an update of the `ConcreteProperty` attached to the combobox, not the other one (they are separate objects). The visible `ConcreteProperty` is unaffected.

To make this work, you need to move the signal attachment + the slot out of the combo box object. The following is a replacement for the two parts —

```
class ConcreteStrengthComboBox(QtWidgets.QComboBox):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(ConcreteStrengthComboBox, self).__init__(parent)

        self.addItems(["C12/15","C16/20","C20/25","C25/30","C30/37","C35/45","C40/50","C45/55",
                       "C50/60","C55/67","C60/75","C70/85","C80/95","C90/105"])

        self.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Helvetica", 10, QtGui.QFont.Normal, italic=False))

        self.compressive_strength = ["12","16","20","25","30","35","40","45","50","55",
                                     "60","70","80","90"]




class ConcreteStrengthInFo(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ConcreteStrengthInFo, self).__init__(parent)

        hbox = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        concrete_strength = QtWidgets.QLabel("Concrete strength: ")
        hbox.addWidget(concrete_strength)

        self.concreteproperty = ConcreteProperty()
        self.concretestrengthbox = ConcreteStrengthComboBox()
        hbox.addWidget(self.concretestrengthbox)


        self.concretestrengthbox.activated.connect(self.setdatastrength)

        self.vlay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.vlay.addLayout(hbox)
        self.vlay.addLayout(self.concreteproperty.concretestrength_lay)


    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int)
    def setdatastrength(self, index):
        it = self.concretestrengthbox.compressive_strength[index]
        print(it)
        self.concreteproperty.display_condata(it)
```

This works for me locally.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and help. You are right, I my case the signal should emit an int of index, I am quite aware of it. I corrected it as you suggested, but it still does not work.

Comment: @Zar  Kha can you update your question with your current code. And when you say "doesn't work" describe what happens.

Comment: The current code and question is updated. An explanation is added to underline the issue.

Comment: @ZarKha updated, I think the issue is you're adding items to a layout but then not applying that layout to anything. The widgets aren't not updating, they're invisible.

Comment: I think the same, it is something about layout somewhere is missing a self. I do not know, that is why I seek any help.

Comment: @ZarKha see the last part of my answer — add `self.setLayout(self.concretestrength_lay)` to your `ConcreteProperty.__init__`

Comment: I did as you suggeted and previously I also tried out some other way. It seems not working out, even I do add `self.setLayout(self.concretestrength_lay)`. I do not think so it would work likely that. Have you tried and run the code above?

Comment: @ZarKha the issue I think is you create 2 ConcreteProperty() objects — one you actually display, the other a child of the combobox. Changing the combo box is only updating the one that is the child of the combobox, which has no effect on the visible one.

Comment: @ZarKha the code you've posted still doesn't work for me (you still have 2 `ConcreteProperty` objects)

Comment: The code above is corrected and now should work. I've posted, so others get benefit from it. My thanks go to you for helping.  But according to PyQt5 documentation using `activation` slot, should give upstart index of visible `Qcombobox` value. But my case wont do it.